# How to remove flash component completely in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

We are developing a flex component, which will appear only after user login. Now the problem is am using

```
if ($('#flashComponentId').length > 0) 
    $('#flashComponentId').remove();
```

to remove the flash component completely from the page. This is working perfectly fine in all browsers `except IE` . I cant remove the parent div of the flash component as it has included other child divs. So how can i do remove the component completely in IE?

Comment: could you just wrap it another div then remove that div?

Comment: or if it is IE, don't load flash conponent, that's if you are calling it via js, but zgood's idea is good. Oh in IE, does the if statement work? as in does it actually go into the execution part?

Comment: Yes it comes inside the if statement,  but still the component is not getting removed:(

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Do you mean that you're developing a Flex Application (AKA SWF File) and want to remove the SWF from the page using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$("#containingDiv embed").remove();
$("#containingDiv object").remove();
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DRxW4/

Comment: thanks for your reply.. but this is also not working.. the thing is after doing the above steps the swf object is getting removed from the DOM, because i cant find that in the inspect element window, but the the swf object is still present sowewhere..

Comment: What do you mean by 'the the swf object is still present sowewhere'? It stops playing sounds and disappears from the screen, so isn't that all what you need?

Comment: Its captures camera and sends a live streaming. Now even if i clear the component, i can the streaming sent by this in other browsers